# Too verbose logs when downloading artifacts in Maven

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, dependency-management

My console output when running Maven build is polluted with

```
[INFO] Logged in - repository.hid.com
[INFO] Downloading: s3://repository.hid.com/release/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.6/slf4j-api-1.7.6.pom
[INFO] Logged off - repository.hid.com
[INFO] Transfers: 1 Time: 43ms Amount: 0 bytes Throughput: 0.000 bytes/s
[INFO] Logged in - repository.hid.com
[INFO] Downloading: s3://repository.hid.com/release/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.7.6/slf4j-parent-1.7.6.pom
[INFO] Logged off - repository.hid.com
[INFO] Transfers: 1 Time: 41ms Amount: 0 bytes Throughput: 0.000 bytes/s
[INFO] Logged in - repository.hid.com
[INFO] Downloading: s3://repository.hid.com/release/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.pom
[INFO] Logged off - repository.hid.com
```

In `settings.xml` this repository is configured like

```
<server>
  <id>repository.hid.com</id>
  <username>usr</username>
  <password>pwd</password>
</server>
```

and then in `pom.xml`:

```
 <repository>
    <id>repository.hid.com</id>
    <url>s3://repository.hid.com/release</url>
</repository>
```

Is it possible to get rid of `Logged in` and `Logged off` messages or at least make just one connection per all artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out the logger name and then set the logger to error

**Find the logger instance**

In the file `<MAVEN_HOME>/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties`.
Change `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=true`
Find the logger which logs `Logged in` and `Logged off`

**disable info logs for the logger instance**

If logger instance is `org.apache.maven.x.y.z`
then set `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.x.y.z = error`

this should not log info logs for that logger instance

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. use either the `--no-transfer-progress` or `--batch-mode` parameter to suppress transfer progress output.
2. pipe the output through `grep` to strip away all the downloading/downloaded messages without stripping away the uploading/uploaded messages.

In other words, you need to do this:

```
mvn --batch-mode ... bla bla bla ... | grep -v 'Download.* http'
```